# Is it possible to declare a variable in C, the name of which is given by the user at runtime?

Tags: c, variables

Is it possible to declare a variable in C, the name of which is given by the user at runtime? If yes, then how?

Comment: no,but what will you do once you define the variable?

Comment: Trust me; this is a horrible idea.  You want to use a collection of some sort, probably something that allows you to use a key to lookup a value (i.e., a has table or something similar).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

No, this is not possible: variable names do not survive the compilation step, becoming addresses and offsets "baked into" the compiled binary code.

It is, however, possible to declare a variable the name of which is given by the developer at compile-time by using a `-D` or a comparable option of your C compiler.

Answer (score 2):

As dasblinkenlight has correctly answered, no.

What you can do and might achieve your implementation goals, is to create and maintain at runtime your own dictionary of strings and associated values.